# Please add a tag search functionality to Careers

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, tags, jobs, search

First, if this is the wrong place then I have to say that someone needs to fix the links in the footer of Careers site (this is how I ended here).

Anyway, I was looking for "C" jobs, and found lots of unrelated jobs instead, and lots I mean LOTS. Thus the site is impossible to use.

I want a C job, not C++, Obj-C, or even things that are not even related at all (I got returns for perl, python, mysql, and lots of other random stuff).

So, Careers site should have a way to search only what you want, maybe use SO search system, where if you type [c] it will search ONLY, and ONLY REALLY ONLY the tag C (instead of random words in the description that contains the character C).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the official answer:

> It’ll pick up objective-c jobs too, due to the search engine looking
>   for ‘c’ between word boundaries. Hyphen is considered a word boundary.
>
> (Background: we don’t do a strict tag search since employers don’t do
>   a great job of tagging, so we do a full-text search on the job. In the
>   case of the C# job, you’ll see that C is mentioned in its
>   description.)

The status is deferred because we're working on switching job search over to [Elastic](http://www.elasticsearch.org/), which will minimize or eliminate this issue.

Comment: I tried that too... the result is STILL wrong: http://imgur.com/2wLkBP0

Comment: @speeder Ah. You are correct. Sorry!

Comment: Thanks. That still do not explain some things I've got (some do not even have C character in any of the found tags...)

Comment: @speeder It's not doing a search on tags only. It's also a full text search of the job description. I think right now its a simple SQL search which is why it's a little hit or miss.

Comment: Yes, I found also something else that worsens the behaviour: When you click "relocation" or "remote" the system switch from "tag" to normal search (giving some 100% bogus results)

Comment: Any updates, over a year later?